# Fetch json data using Regex on linux

Tags: json, linux, jq

I know we should use JQ for parsing json data, but I want to parse it using regex. I want to fetch the value of a json key into a variable in my shell script. As of now, I am using  JQ for parsing.

So my abc.json is

```
{"value1":5.0,"value2":2.5,"value3":"2019-10-24T15:26:00.000Z","modifier":[],"value4":{"value41":{"value411":5}}}
```

Currently, my XYZ.sh has these lines to fetch the data

data1 =$(cat abc.json | jq -r '.value4.value41.value411')

I want data1 to have value of value411. How can I achieve this?

ps- The JSON is mutable. The above JSON is just a part of the JSON file that I want to fetch.

Comment: Reliably, you can't do this with a regex. For any pattern we conceive, it will be easy to provide some json that would evade the matching.

Comment: Isn't there any way to do this ? i have been stuck on this problem since very long

Comment: I think a single regex does not work, but a cascade of them could do. I mean - extract the whole intended key (ex. "value4"), then extract another key/value pair (ex. "value41")... and so on.

Comment: @user18148705 - Unless you can indicate some additional assumptions that one can make, this question will most likely be closed as ill-formed or unanswerable.  E.g., can we assume that the key "value411" is unique in the JSON?  That its value is a scalar?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Have made those changes

Answer (score 2):

Is your json structure immutable? If you have to use it, consider the following

```bash
┌──[root@vms83.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$cat abc.json  | awk -F: '{print $NF}' | grep -o '[[:digit:]]'
5
```

Comment: Thank you thank you so mucchhhhhh. Could you please explain what this is doing exactly ??? It would really mean a lot

Comment: `jq` is the way to go on this.

Comment: You're welcome,`awk` gets the last `:` split entry `5}}}`, `grep -o` matches the number

Comment: Actually problem is this will be applicable to only this example, but it wont work for this {"value1":5.0,"value2":2.5,"value3":"2019-10-24T15:26:00.000Z","modifier":[],"value4":{"value41":5},"value6":9}. It will return 9. So can we fetch data based on key ?

Comment: Well, if the `JSON` structure is mutable, this is not a suitable solution, but you can try traversing the columns by awk, getting the position of the entries, and then getting what you want by regularizing ，类似这样 `$cat abc.json  | awk -F: '{for (i = 1;i <= NF;i++) if($i ~ /value411/) print $(i+1) }' | grep -o '[[:digit:]]'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74315715/how-to-execute-regex-using-grep?noredirect=1#comment131199906_74315715  Could  you please help me w this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem was you had a space between `data` and `=`. There can't be a space there.

This works as you want it to (I removed the unnecessary `cat`)

```
data1=$(jq -r '.value4.value41.value411' abc.json)
echo $data1
```

Comment: Yes the jq is working for me. But I want to use regex for it.  As that is the requirement